# A trigonometric sum

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, summation, trigonometric-series

For $k=0,\cdots, m$ and $l=0,\cdots 2m+1$ let us put
$$ \alpha_{kl}=\frac{4k-4l+1}{4(m+1)}\pi\quad  \beta_{kl}=\frac{4k+4l+3}{4(m+1)}\pi $$

and

$$x_{kl}=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{1}{\sin\alpha_{kl}}+\frac{1}{\sin\beta_{kl}}    \Big)$$

$$y_{kl}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\Big(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha_{kl})}{\sin\alpha_{kl}}+\frac{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4}-\beta_{kl})}{\sin(\beta_{kl})}    \Big)
   $$

$$z_{kl}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\sin\frac{\alpha_{kl}}{2}}{\sin\alpha_{kl}}-\frac{\sin\frac{\beta_{kl}}{2}}{\sin\beta_{kl}}\Big)$$

How can we show that $x_{kl}+y_{kl}+z_{kl}>0$ ?

Comment: Having been on Math.SE for a while, you should know that the community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc.) This helps answerers avoid wasting time explaining things you already understand. ... That said, if my quick *Mathematica* calculation is correct, the sum simplifies rather nicely.

Comment: To prove the invertibility of a principal submatrix of discrete sine transform matrix of type 1, I faced to this problem. I  checked it by MATLAB but could not find any clear approach to get that.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that the sum reduces to (ignoring subscripts)
$$\frac{\sin\frac14(\alpha+\beta)}{4\sin\frac14(\pi-\alpha)\;\sin\frac14(\pi+\beta)}$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: Great, it is helpful. Please write details.